# Why won't this MySQL trigger execute properly?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, triggers

I am working on a wordpress installation for a client.
An ecommerce plugin he's selected does not integrate well with Wordpress Users.
I am trying to insert new records into the plugin's user account system when a new user record is created in wordpress.
To me, it seemed that a trigger on the wp_users table copying the user data to the plugin table before insert would do the trick. Simple enough.
However, in my testing i can't get the wp_users table trigger to do anything. New User Account creation hangs and prevents data insert to wp_users if the trigger event is Before Insert or After Insert. When Specifying Before Update, it allows data insertion in wp_users but not the Plugin table.
At no time has it correctly executed the trigger.
Here is my Code:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  `user_update`//
CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`user_update`
AFTER INSERT
ON `wp_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `test_data_dump` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `first_name`, `created_at`) VALUES(user_login, user_pass, user_email, user_nicename, user_registered);
END
```

Any insight would help immensley.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble would be with this line. You need to use the word `new` when you're referencing the newly inserted data:

```
INSERT INTO 'test_data_dump' ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'created_at')
    VALUES (new.user_login, new.user_pass, new.user_email, new.user_nicename, new.user_registered);
```

**EDIT**: Assuming all your table columns and names match, this syntax should work:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS user_update;

CREATE TRIGGER user_update AFTER INSERT ON wp_users
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO test_data_dump ('username', 'password', 'email', 'first_name', 'created_at')
    VALUES (new.user_login, new.user_pass, new.user_email, new.user_nicename, new.user_registered); 
END;
```

Comment: Throwing errors... should I also be specifying old.username, etc in the insert into statement?

Comment: There is `old` on an UPDATE, but not on an INSERT trigger.

Comment: Then I guess I'll ask how would YOU do this, because I can't even get the trigger to save without syntax errors. I am tyring to use DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `user_update_trigger`//
CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`user_update_trigger`
AFTER INSERT
ON `semics5_users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO `dbname.`semics5_test_data_dump` (`username`, `password`, `email`, `first_name`, `created_at`) VALUES (new.user_login, new.user_pass, new.user_email, new.user_nicename, new.user_registered);
END//;

Comment: Here is the error: A SQL error occured (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '// CREATE TRIGGER `dbname`.`user_update_trigger` AFTER INSERT ON `semics5_us' at line 1

Comment: Sorry, Didn't work. Cna't figure this one out. Still does not allow the data to be inserted into either table. Goin out of my mind on this seemingly simple task. Thank you for your help however.

Comment: Don't understand tis situation. Thanks, but your update did not run, I added the new.user_registered); that was omitted to no avial. I was unable to save a new user in wp_users or copy new data to dump table. Do all column names need to be exactly the same? I thought I could use this to populate fields in another table if I defined the taget.

Comment: The trigger was saved without error but did not execute. This is on my localhost test enviroment with super privleges.